# Swift for TensorFlowがPlaygroundで動作しない

Tags: swift, tensorflow

XcodeでPlaygroundを実行したところ、エラーメッセージが表示されて動作しません。

[手順]
下記サイトを参考にXcode betaとSwift for TensorFlowを導入しました。
https://github.com/tensorflow/swift/blob/master/Usage.md

Xcode beta上でToolchainsにSwift for TensorFlowを設定した後に、サイトを参考にPlaygroundで以下のコードを実行したところエラーが発生しました。

```
import TensorFlow

let x = Tensor<Float>([[1, 2], [3, 4]])
print(x)
```

[エラーメッセージ]
The LLDB RPC server has crashed.

上記エラーの解消方法を教えてください。
よろしくお願いします。

Answer (score 1):

はじめまして。同じようにTensorFlowを導入してみましたが、同じように落ちるようです。
こちらの環境は、

- macOS X 10.14 (Mojave)
- Xcode 10.0 (App Storeからダウンロードのため、β番ではありません）
- TensorFlow 質問にあったもの? (September 17, 2018 非CUDA版です)

と、なりますが、

- Useageに記述のあったREPLは、`/Library/Developer/Toolchains/swift-latest/usr/bin/swift`を`Terminal`から起動し、REPLサンプルを実行　→　正常動作
- `Xcode`の`Toolchain`を変更し、`Playground`を作成して質問にあったサンプルを入力 → RPCエラー

その際のエラーの具体的な内容は
`~/Library/Logs/DiagnosticReports`というディレクトリーに、
`lldb-rpc-server_[日付]-[プロセス番号？]_[自分のマシン名].crash`
というファイルが作成されており、内容を確認すると、

```
Process:               lldb-rpc-server [62885]
Path:                  /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/SharedFrameworks/LLDBRPC.framework/Versions/A/Resources/lldb-rpc-server
Identifier:            lldb-rpc-server
Version:               2
Code Type:             X86-64 (Native)
Parent Process:        Xcode [62870]
Responsible:           lldb-rpc-server [62885]
User ID:               501

Date/Time:             2018-10-06 03:56:20.527 +0900
OS Version:            Mac OS X 10.14 (18A391)
Report Version:        12
Bridge OS Version:     3.0 (16P375)
Anonymous UUID:        52707192-7890-DB55-F0A7-F9A15E883136


Time Awake Since Boot: 780000 seconds

System Integrity Protection: enabled

Crashed Thread:        6  <lldb.process.internal-state(pid=62905)>

Exception Type:        EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGSEGV)
Exception Codes:       KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at 0x0000000000000000
Exception Note:        EXC_CORPSE_NOTIFY

Termination Signal:    Segmentation fault: 11
Termination Reason:    Namespace SIGNAL, Code 0xb
Terminating Process:   exc handler [62885]

VM Regions Near 0:
-->
    __TEXT                 0000000109f1d000-0000000109fae000 [  580K] r-x/rwx SM=COW  /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/SharedFrameworks/LLDBRPC.framework/Versions/A/Resources/lldb-rpc-server

Thread 0:: Connection::RunLoop() packet reading thread  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib              0x00007fff720888a6 read + 10
1   lldb-rpc-server                     0x0000000109f26f37 rpc_common::RPCConnectionSocket::Read(std::__1::basic_string<unsigned char, std::__1::char_traits<unsigned char>, std::__1::allocator<unsigned char> >&, bool) + 173
2   lldb-rpc-server                     0x0000000109f2dab7 rpc_common::Connection::ReceivePacket(rpc_common::RPCPacket&) + 149
3   lldb-rpc-server                     0x0000000109f2d5c0 rpc_common::Connection::RunLoop() + 152
4   lldb-rpc-server                     0x0000000109f6fbfe main + 494
5   libdyld.dylib                       0x00007fff71f4e085 start + 1
```

と、なっていることから、`import`した`TensorFlow`は、`RPC`（リモートプロシジャコール）という仕組みで別プロセスを起動し、そこにデーターを渡して処理をする仕組みになっているようですが、その処理して欲しいデーターを、処理のために起動したプロセスに渡すところで失敗しているようです。

まず調べてわかったのはここまでで、これ以上は`TensorFlow`をソースからビルドして`Swift for TensorFlow`の中身を修正しないといけないとおもいますので
作者にバグレポートを送って修正されるのを待つのが今の段階ではよいような気がします。

質問からは@Shinichiro Yogoさんが`Swift`や、Macの`PRC`という仕組みをどれ位ご存じか判断しかねるので、もし、@Shinichiro Yogoさんにこのソースを追跡して、バグを見つけ、直す熱意がおありでしたらそれも良いと思います。

Comment: Чайка様、回答ありがとうございます。
ご指摘の通り、TensorFlowのバージョンはSeptember 17, 2018 非CUDA版を使用しています。
ソースを追跡する熱意まではないので、Swift for TensorFlow以外の機械学習フレームワークを検討しようと思います。

Comment: OS 10.14 (Mojave)からは、`Core ML`というApple独自の機械学習フレームワークも提供されているので、ドキュメントはまだ少ないですが、こちらを使って見るのも手かと思います。